# creating dismissable bootstrap v3 alerts when using redux-form error rendering

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following redux-form (v6.5.0) sources:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
render() {
    const {error} = this.props
    return (
            <form>
                    <Field.....>
                    {this.renderError(error)}
            </form>
           );
}
renderError(error) {
    if (error) {
        var temp = error;
        return (
                <div className='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                <div className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</div>
                {temp}
                </div>
               );
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
}
```

Now I see an error message as a bootstrap alert whenever a submissionError is thrown from my handleSubmit function.

However, the error alert box does not go away when I click on the x button. What am I doing wrong ?

I even tried to clear the error props manually but I could not do it. Any other suggestion on how to get bootstrap3 alerts working with react/redux-form ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatching the `stopSubmit` action with an empty `errors` object will clear it

```
import {stopSubmit} from 'redux-form';
dispatch(stopSubmit('myFormName', {}))
```

Original answer from Github: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2604#issuecomment-282670843

*Ran into this problem myself. Didn't find any more convenient way to do this.*

**UPD:**
tested with "react-redux" v6.7.0

Comment: I no longer use bootstrap alerts and redux-form together. I will mark your answer as accepted if you have verified that it is working. Thanks.